# Lottery Ball problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-distributions

There are two sets of numbered balls. One set consits of white balls numbered $1-10$ the other is blue balls numbered $1-20$. To play you select two white balls and two blue balls. What is the probability that your ticket contains exactly one matching white number and two matching blue numbers?

My 1st thought, $\dfrac{C(10,1)\cdot C(20,2)}{8550}$ but thats not right.

The total number of combinations I can make is $C(20,2) \cdot C(10,2)=8550$ (I took a shortcut). Now I want to choose 1 white ball that matches and 2 blue balls that match which gives me $1900$ when multiplied out. But this does not give me the answer. Why?

Comment: Can you tell us why did you write this? What was the reasoning line?

Comment: Also, would you please describe the number on the lottery ticket? like how many they are? what set o digits? any special thing?

Comment: The ticket has to do with the blue and white balls. You choose a blue ball numbered 1-20 and a white ball from 1-10. This cooresponds to your ticket.

Comment: How many digits does the ticket have? are they 0-9? are they all different?

Comment: The number of digits depends on what numbers you have chosen. If I chose 9,9,10,10 that gives me 6 digits. If I chose 1,1,1,1 that gives me 4 digits. I don't think this is relevant to the problem. The digits is dependent on what numbers you choose

Comment: The 8550 is correct, may be this is a language problem, can you show me some successful outcomes? Some of the outcomes that we are looking for?

Comment: We are looking for the outcome of having 2 blue ball numbers match and 1 white ball number matching. For example there is only 1 way for 2 white balls and 2 blue balls to match the lottery ticket, there is also 8449 ways for no balls to match. So how will I calculate the number of ways 2 blue balls and 1 white ball match?

Comment: If I understand the problem correctly, the numerator should be $16$.

Comment: How did you get 16?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't the numerator just be 2 * 8?

There's only one way to pick the blue balls, C(2,2), two ways to pick the right number, C(2,1) and 8 ways to pick the wrong number C(8,1).

$\frac{16}{8550}$

Comment: why do you omit the fact that there are 20 blue balls and 10 white balls?

Comment: Well the fact that there are 20 blue and 10 white balls is reflected in the denominator.